# How to refer kendo grid column to nested field or multiple fields?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm using kendi ui grid and have two questions:

1. Lets say each item in my collection is as follows:

> ```
> { id: "1", 
>     properties: { 
>           color: red, 
>           width: 100 }
> }
> ```

How do I set a column field to be "properties.color" or "properties.width"?

1. How do I combine two fields in the same column. If I want color and width to be in the same column?

Answer (score 0):

Using a template in your column definition, you can refer to any property on your data item; so you could do something like this to display both values:

```
{
    field: "properties",
    template: "<span style='display: inline-block; width: 80%; height: 100%; background-color: #= properties.color #'></span><span> #= properties.width #</span>"
}
```

([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lhoeppner/JEnSs/3/))

If you want it to be editable, you'll need to [create the editor manually](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/grid#configuration-columns.editor).

Comment: @julius was that what you were looking for or do you still need help with this?